# Can't open a mpg-File for capture using EmguCV with C#

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

I'm trying to open a mpg-File using emguCV. I use the following code:

```
    if (instance == null)
    {
        lock (m_lock)
        {
            try
            {
                instance = new Capture(0);  // capture from camera works fine if a camera is connected
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                String sFileName = @"C:\tmp\MarkerMovie.mpg";


                try
                {
                    if (File.Exists(sFileName))
                    {
                        instance = new Capture(sFileName);  // here the exception is thrown
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No Camera and no Video-File found");
                    }
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Couldn't open Video: "+sFileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If a webcam is connected everything works fine, but when I unplug the webcam the line `instance = new Capture(sFileName);` throws a NullReferenceException:

> Message = "Unable to create capture from C:\tmp\MarkerMovie.mpg"

I debugged and found the reason is in the constructor of capture. The following command always returns a Null-Pointer:

```
_ptr = CvInvoke.cvCreateFileCapture(fileName);
```

I could open the same video using C++ using this code:

```
cap = cvCaptureFromFile("C:\\tmp\\MarkerMovie.mpg");
```

I'm new to openCV, so I'm not sure which information you need to help me. I installed emguCV yesterday from http://sourceforge.net/projects/emgucv/ on a Windows XP computer. The installer-version is x86_2.3.0.1416. I included opencv_core231.dll, opencv_highgui231.dll and opencv_imgproc231.dll to my project.

Does somebody know how I can make this code working?
Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Steckl, I cant see anything wrong with your code, I tend to use an openfiledialog to prevent any null exception and just leave me with codec problems but your error is strange. Start by trying am Openfiledialog and pointing the program directly to the file. If you still get an error is there any way you could upload your project or a simpler version with the video so I can recreate the error and see if I can debug the issue directly. Cheers

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your reply. I tried using an OpenFileDialog, but without any success. I uploaded the Project to [link](http://db.tt/bUwxRCMQ). . The Zip-File Contains the project and the video. I just uploaded all files of the project (Didn't know which are relevant for running it). The code in my posting is in file VideoStream.cs. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and adding the opencv_ffmpeg.dll to the project seems to solve it. (Found in the bin directory in the Emgu CV directory) I have tried it on the project that you posted and it seems to be working too. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had no time yet to test your solution, but I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: I had time to try it today and it works perfect. Thank you very much for your answer! :-)

Answer (score 0):

With EmguCV in C#, you need to put the opencv_ffmpeg.dll, for example: opencv_ffmpeg2410.dll, be careful if you have x86 or 64 bits